# My if statement doesn't work as intended

Tags: jquery

So I've created a function that I thought was pretty solid. If .button has class active AND either .amd or .intel have class active, do this. If not, do that. I was pretty pleased with myself because I have almost 0 knowledge of jQuery in general and have been learning by trying my own things and doing codecademy. However upon close inspection, the function doesn't work. It adds active to .build regardless of if .button has active or not. It only checks to see if .amd or .intel are active. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
  var checkActive = (function() {
    if ($(".button").hasClass("active") && ($(".amd").hasClass("amdactive") || $(".intel").hasClass("intelactive"))) {
        $(".build").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".build").removeClass("active");
    }
    });
```

this function is then used in my other code:

```
$(function() {    
$(".button").click(function() {  
    if ( $(this).hasClass("amd") ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("amdactive"),
        $(".intel").removeClass("intelactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'),
        checkActive(); }
    else if ( $(this).hasClass("intel") ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("intelactive"),
        $(".amd").removeClass("amdactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'),
        checkActive();}
    else {$(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'),
    checkActive();}    
  });
});
```

Comment: Is checkActive called multiple times?

Comment: Can you share the corresponding html as well?

Comment: @Jay yes is that an issue?

Comment: Is there more than one element with class `button`?

Comment: It's working perfectly -> **http://jsfiddle.net/653bqdw6/**

Comment: As a sidenote, you don't need parenthesis around your functions, and you don't end lines with commas.

Comment: Guys I just twigged what I've done. It's because I have the class .button applied to quite a few elements, including the amd and intel elements ( so that they were styled the same) If I fix that it should work! Thanks for the help

Comment: @adeneo To be pedantic, your fiddle doesn't demonstrate that it works. OP says the condition is ignored, but in your fiddle the condition is true. The condition should be false in order to show that it is not ignored.

Comment: @Oriol - Nope, the OP states *"... It adds `active` to `.build` regardless of if `.button` has `active` or not."*, which my fiddle clearly shows isn't the case.

Comment: @adeneo the problem is the code worked, but my HTML was causing issues with how I labelled classes.